# Amazon s3 domain name routing to endpoint instead of serving only index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Recently I tried to host my website on Amazon s3 by following steps on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html ..On Step 5 I created Alias which will route to endpoint. Now, On typing www.example.com it is redirecting to  http://example.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/index.html instead of www.example.com/index.html

How can I route only for example.com instead of endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced getting started example how to [Associate a Domain Name with Your Website Using Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html) is using the increasingly preferred approach to host a website on the domain root, likely because it is slightly more involved and support for this via [Route 53 Alias Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html) being worth mentioning/showcasing.

The [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) developer guide also features an example for [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html), which is a bit more explicit about the arbitrary choice which of your two buckets will be the redirection target, see [Step 2: Create Two Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-s3-tasks):

> In this example, to support requests from both the root domain such as
>   example.com and subdomain such as www.example.com, you will create two
>   buckets. **One bucket will contain the content and you will configure
>   the other bucket to redirect requests**. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

All you need to do is to effectively inverse the configuration instructions for `example.com` vs. `www.example.com` (starting from step 2.1.3) to redirect requests from the former root domain bucket to the latter instead of the other way round.

Comment: Do you mean www.example.com should have code and example.com should have redirection?

Comment: Yes, if I understood your goal correctly, i.e. you always want your users to end up at `www.example.com` even if they just enter `example.com`?!

Comment: Well, that is not my goal..For me example.com or www.example.com is redirecting to endpoint like  http://example.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/index.html instead of just http://example.com/index.html...Is this expected for redirection to endpoint?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion..my bad..it is browser cache redirecting to endpoint Once I cleared my cookies..It is redirecting fine..Thank you for your valuable time..

Answer (score 0):

Yout problem appears to be [in the prior step](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-hosting-your-website.html).

> In the **Redirect all requests to** box, type the name of your root domain.

The behavior you describe would occur if, instead of just the desired target, "example.com," you entered the entire S3 web endpoint hostname (e.g., example.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com) there.

Comment: It is example.com only..It is not endpoint for me in Redirect all requests box

Comment: Thanks for your time..It is redirecting fine now